# Let other computers view local / Apache sites on my machine

Tags: apache, http

I'm currently using DAMP to build Drupal sites locally and wondered how I might go about letting users on other machines on my network view these sites?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Simply add new VirtualHost for each site - for example "drupal1.test.local" 
-than find out your local IP address - something like "192.168.1.25
-on other machines you have to edit "hosts" file > add a new line on the end of this file by pattern:

```
your-ip-address website
```

So by my example, it would look like:

```
192.168.1.25 drupal1.test.local
```

Hope it will help:)

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but how would I do that? I understand how to edit the other users host files, but adding the VirtualHost on my machine(Mac)?

Comment: by "DAMP" you mean the thing by Acquia?  If yes, i'm sorry for misinformation - I think you don't have to set up any virtual host (it is done by the application). So just simply config the host file.

Comment: Yeah, the Acquia thingummy. My machine's on a corporate network so there were issues running MAMP or the built in Apache / SQL / php set up. Will give this a try! Thanks!

Comment: I spoke too soon, sorry.

`my-ip-address website`

simply returns a directory listing on my own machine.

Comment: i'm not if i described it well: if the machine which is hosting the site drupal1.local has IP address 192.168.1.25 than you have to edit hosts file on other machine (which is used to access the page only) and the line in hosts file will look like "192.168.1.25 drupal1.local"

Comment: Ok, so the solution I found (for mac) was this:

Web sharing was turned on, but I still wasn't able to broadcast the URL to my network in the form my-ip-address sitename

However my-ip-address:portnumber worked, and adding this to the hosts file on other user's machines worked. Phew! Thanks though!